# Generate random users with patronymic

Tags: java, http

Suppose, I have this simple entity

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String patronymic;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private Sex sex;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        return id.equals(person.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Person.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("name='" + name + "'")
                .add("lastName='" + lastName + "'")
                .add("patronymic='" + patronymic + "'")
                .add("dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth)
                .add("sex=" + sex)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

I need to generate random persons. HTTP APIs, like `https://randomuser.me/api/`, seem to be a good way to go. But the thing is if I perform a GET request to that endpoint, I may receive something like

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "Mr",
        "first": "Marius",
        "last": "Lefebvre"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": {
          "number": 4993,
          "name": "Rue Dugas-Montbel"
        },
        "city": "Mulhouse",
        "state": "Pyrénées-Orientales",
        "country": "France",
        "postcode": 26699,
        "coordinates": {
          "latitude": "-15.4130",
          "longitude": "-53.1324"
        },
        "timezone": {
          "offset": "-3:30",
          "description": "Newfoundland"
        }
      },
      "email": "marius.lefebvre@example.com",
      "login": {
        "uuid": "9847d8c2-aed9-4f16-8e7c-7a1134bb954f",
        "username": "heavyrabbit505",
        "password": "toonarmy",
        "salt": "O42M0eyb",
        "md5": "24da836fc005d5de28c02bba8eb71762",
        "sha1": "ea42735cc6db2c9b7d6294522ab35b6d5a98d935",
        "sha256": "a05ef824f11b544386834ab455424b92e583ee6c82dbc6b1dd7a7e812fc1bf74"
      },
      "dob": {
        "date": "1983-05-07T23:19:24.773Z",
        "age": 40
      },
      "registered": {
        "date": "2004-03-16T02:14:38.456Z",
        "age": 19
      },
      "phone": "02-26-76-33-91",
      "cell": "06-22-36-16-05",
      "id": {
        "name": "INSEE",
        "value": "1830497805013 11"
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/6.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/6.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/6.jpg"
      },
      "nat": "FR"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "seed": "aac7138ecf098b1e",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.4"
  }
}
```

This JSON contains a lot of data. But for my purposes I only need a name, a last name, a gender, and a date of birth. I may use a `RestTemplate`. But I don't feel like creating a whole separate class just so that Jackson have something to map that JSON to (and then, perhaps, use Mapstruct to map it to my original entity). It seems it's a lot of work for something that trivial

The issue number two is that I need a patronymic. It's not common for people's names to have a patronymics unless they live in Eastern Europe so the chances of finding an HTTP API that sends JSONs with patronymics are low. I may issue a separate request for each randomly fetched person to get a male, extract the first name, and use some custom function to turn it into a patronymic (for example, "Joseph" → "Josephovych"). That means if I need to generate a million random users, it would take two million HTTP requests which is a lot (twice as many)

What approach would you recommend to achieve my goal?

Comment: There are several Java libraries that allow to generate random data matching some constraints. You should look in this direction IMHO. For instance https://github.com/datafaker-net/datafaker. There are others that I don't remember.

Comment: If it's just test data, then why not 'patronymicize' the first name of the same person?

Comment: @g00se because it would be too silly (unrealistic) for all of the people to have patronymics that match their first names

Comment: @GaëlJ thank you. But the problem is a randomly generated gender should match the name. It doesn't seem possible to achieve that with `Faker`

Comment: Right - point taken, but you could randomly choose from other users you've already created maybe

Comment: Is this for tests or not? For tests, I would question the relevancy to have realistic patronymic. What are you trying to test? Otherwise (if not for tests), you'll have to implement something yourself that match some "rules" for realistic patronymic then.

Comment: @GaëlJ, that's just what I was about to ask ;)

Comment: @GaëlJ it's part of an entry test for a job

Comment: Then it doesn't need to be realistic

Comment: @GaëlJ may I ask you where those random names are coming from? I can't believe they are all hard-coded. And if it makes some HTTP requests anyway, then how does it matter compared to my suggestion?

Comment: No idea, you can look at the code but 99% sure it doesn't call any service. It's probably a few hardcoded values + some strings generated randomly.

Comment: But it is somewhat of an issue that names don't match genders if I choose to use `Faker`